# Get the first message of every conversation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-design, stored-procedures

I have one table to store all the messages sent inside of a xmpp service. I'm looking to create a query to get all the conversations and the first message of it (like whatsapp in chat logs).

Here is my table.

[image]

`FromPersonId` and `ToPersonId` are ids for people. What I do is, for example I want to see all the conversations of the personId = 643

```
SELECT DISTINCT MA.FromPersonId, MA.ToPersonId, MAX(MA.SENTDATE) AS [Date], Body
    FROM MessageArchive AS MA
    WHERE MA.FromPersonId = @personId OR MA.ToPersonId = @personId
    GROUP BY MA.FromPersonId, MA.ToPersonId, Body
    ORDER BY [Date] DESC
```

Above is what I have. And the result is

[image]

As you see, the result is for the same conversation. But cannot distinguish that is the same conversation because are the same people but in different position.

How can I fix this?

Comment: So, is every row duplicated like that?. What is the point of storing the same conversation with the "from" and "to" reversed?, is it an error of your app?

Comment: Can use something like CASE WHEN FromPersonId < ToPersonId THEN CAST(FromPersonId AS varchar(10)) + '-' + CAST(ToPersonId AS varchar(10)) ELSE CAST(ToPersonId AS varchar(10)) + '-' + CAST(FromPersonId AS varchar(10)) END AS ConversationLabel and group by that instead maybe.

Comment: Also I was going to bring up what Lamak said about them sending the same message to each other in the same millisecond, but I assume this is test data and your question is more focused on how to group those two rows together as one conversation.

Comment: Are we just not seeing the 644 to 643 piece in your screenshot?

Comment: When I look at your sample data, I can't see where the second query result comes from.  In any event, depending on how you define a conversation, you might not have enough data to accomplish this..

Comment: @Lamak no, I just duplicated the record in SQL server just for testing.. is not an error

Comment: @Aushin 1- you are right, is just a test data 2- exactly, that's what I what I want

Comment: @Aushin I like your idea. I'm gonna test it

Answer (score 0):

You miss the 644 to 643 message, supposing it exists, What I recommend is to put a ROW ID autoincremental, this columns can give you exact information about what records come first and what records come after, besides, How do you identify that the message is the same ?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a 'conversation' table, with a conversationID field being a foreign key in your MessageArchive table, as a manifestation of the 'one-to-many' relation existing between the conversation entity and the message entity: one conversation holds at least one message, and each message relates to one, and only one, conversation.

With such a database model, you would be able to collect the 'top 1' message of each conversation.